# import internal data for analysis with python

Tags: python

I have company data stored in my windows desktop. I need to do data analysis for this csv. It's company data, so it's for private use. My Windows disk should already be encrypted. Anything else need to do before I use `pd.read_csv('file.csv')` to import the data to python for analysis?

Comment: I need to make sure data will not disclosure, data is well protected after I import to python? And when I import csv to python, where is this csv stored? it's stil stored in my disk? or import to somewhere else?

Comment: Why don't you just try and see? Any pandas tutorial will describe the process. Ask a question if and when you run into a problem, not before you have even tried.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried. I'm very beginner to python and just want to make sure how to use private data in python. cause python is open source. thanks.

Comment: If you did try but ran into difficulty, it would be better to show what your efforts were and say what the difficulty is (including any error message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to call `import pandas as pd`, and save your Python script in the same folder as `file.csv`.

Comment: thank you for your reply Nathaniel! so save my python code to the same folder with the csv in my windows desktop or in jupytor notebook folder?

Comment: To us ``pd.read_csv('file.csv')`` your Python code should be in the same folder as ``file.csv``. Whether that's on your desktop or in another folder is up to you. Alternatively, you can pass the full file path to the csv and then read into Python from anywhere: ``pd.read_csv('c:/Users/(username)/Desktop/file.csv')``, replacing (username) with your actual username.

Comment: thank you! I will use second way to import file. thanks!